How to implement ReplyingKafkaTemplate with out using @KafkaListener and @SendTo to send response to reply topic
Good Day.
I am trying to implement sync request reply message flow using ReplyingKafkaTemplate. It worked fine as a individual POC. But my application has already kafka implementation to consume the messages manually. I am using ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer as shown below.
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> containerFactory) {

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> repliesContainer =
                containerFactory.createContainer("kReplies");
        repliesContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("repliesGroup");
        repliesContainer.setAutoStartup(false);

        return repliesContainer;
    }

Producer using KafkaTemplate
 ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("kRequests", "foo");
 RequestReplyFuture<String, String, String> replyFuture = template.sendAndReceive(record);
 SendResult<String, String> sendResult = replyFuture.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 System.out.println("Sent ok: " + sendResult.getRecordMetadata());
 ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord = replyFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 System.out.println("Return value: " + consumerRecord.value());

App has custom MessageListener to consume the messages which implements AcknowledgingMessageListener.
public class KafkaListener implements
public class KafkaListener implements AcknowledgingMessageListener {
...
@Override
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord consumeRecord, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
}
}

Above implementation works fine for publishing and consuming messages. But now i am trying to extend this to support Sync Kafka message flow using ReplyingKafkaTemplate. I added ReplyingKafkaTemplate to this framework. It published message to request topic and listener consumed message.
 @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyingTemplate(
            ProducerFactory<String, String> pf,
            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> repliesContainer) {

        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, repliesContainer);
    }


       public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory()           
       throws IOException {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new   
                ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(2);
        factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
        **factory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate);** // to support REPLY_TO topic for req/reply   
                pattern
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
        return factory;
    }


But the response is not published to reply topic. I followed Spring Kafka documentation. I am trying to implement with out @KafkaListener. I want to publish the reply message to reply topic with out using @KafkaListener. Could you please help me on this?
I am looking for a solution to send a response to reply topic with out using @KafkaListener. I tried different solutions avalable over web but somehow, the response message is not publishing to reply topic which resulted in ReplyTime out every time.

If you don't use @KafkaListener, then you simply can use KafkaTemplate directly in your code to produce that reply. That is essentially what is done in the framework internally for the @KafkaListener in its MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.
That ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory is designed exactly for the @KafkaListener. If you use AcknowledgingMessageListener manually, then you are on your own to implement everything yourself.

Thank you Artem. I tried to post the message to reply topic using kafka template from the listener. The message is posted successfully to reply topic. But as i am using ReplyingKafkaTemplate, can i still expect the output by below method.
// get consumer record
consumerRecord = sendAndReceive.get();                                                                                      some how i am not receiving the message response back. Or should i write another listener to reply topic? Please advise.

See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/sending-messages.html#reply-message. I wonder if you are missing to copy KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID from request message to the reply to make the ReplyingKafkaTemplate to be able to correlate a reply with sent request.
